# Error thrown in docker-compose down, up, stop. (Named volume X is used in service Y but no declaration was found in the volumes section.)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I'm trying to build ELK in docker using https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker

But I only need Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash so I removed all the apm_server, filebeat , etc. stuff.

Then, running the command:

`docker-compose -f setup.yml up`

returns the following output:

[image]

After that, every docker-compose command is throwing the same error:

> **ERROR:** Named volume `"es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw"` is used in service `"elasticsearch"` but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

My `setup.yml` is like this:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  setup:
    image: docker/compose:1.21.2
    working_dir: "${PWD}"
    cap_add: ['SYS_ADMIN']
    environment:
      - "PWD=${PWD}"
      - "ELASTIC_PASSWORD"
      - "ELASTIC_VERSION"
      - "TAG"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "${PWD}:${PWD}"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/ash", "-c"]
    command: ['cat ./scripts/setup.sh | tr -d "\r" | ash']

    # command: ["./scripts/setup.sh"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
 ---
version: '3.6'
services:
  # The environment variable "TAG" is used throughout this file to
  # specify the version of the images to run. The default is set in the
  # '.env' file in this folder. It can be overridden with any normal
  # technique for setting environment variables, for example:
  #
  #   TAG=6.0.0-beta1 docker-compose up
  #
  # REF: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution
  #
  # Also be sure to set the ELASTIC_VERSION variable. For released versions,
  # ${TAG} and ${ELASTIC_VERSION} will be identical, but for pre-release
  # versions, ${TAG} might contain an extra build identifier, like
  # "6.0.0-beta1-3eab5b40", so a full invocation might look like:
  #
  #   ELASTIC_VERSION=6.0.0-beta1 TAG=6.0.0-beta1-3eab5b40 docker-compose up
  #
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${TAG}
    container_name: elasticsearch
    secrets:
      - source: ca.crt
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - source: elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - source: elasticsearch.keystore
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
      - source: elasticsearch.key
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key
      - source: elasticsearch.crt
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt
    ports: ['9200:9200']
    networks: ['stack']
    volumes:
      - 'es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
      - './scripts/setup-users.sh:/usr/local/bin/setup-users.sh:ro'
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${TAG}
    container_name: kibana
    secrets:
      - source: kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
      - source: kibana.keystore
        target: /usr/share/kibana/data/kibana.keystore
      - source: ca.crt
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - source: kibana.key
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana/kibana.key
      - source: kibana.crt
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana/kibana.crt
    ports: ['5601:5601']
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:5601 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${TAG}
    container_name: logstash
    secrets:
      - source: logstash.conf
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
      - source: logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - source: logstash.keystore
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.keystore
      - source: ca.crt
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
    healthcheck:
      test: bin/logstash -t
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 50s
      retries: 5

secrets:
  ca.crt:
    file: ./config/ssl/ca/ca.crt
  logstash.yml:
    file: ./config/logstash/logstash.yml
  logstash.keystore:
    file: ./config/logstash/logstash.keystore
  logstash.conf:
    file: ./config/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
  elasticsearch.yml:
    file: ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
  elasticsearch.keystore:
    file: ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore
  elasticsearch.key:
    file: ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key
  elasticsearch.crt:
    file: ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt
  elasticsearch.p12:
    file: ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.p12
  kibana.yml:
    file: ./config/kibana/kibana.yml
  kibana.keystore:
    file: ./config/kibana/kibana.keystore
  kibana.key:
    file: ./config/kibana/kibana.key
  kibana.crt:
    file: ./config/kibana/kibana.crt
```

Comment: Please paste your entire `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: You can view all my project here: https://github.com/Agusnez/lori-elastic-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
networks: {stack: {}}
# use docker volume to persist ES data outside of a container.
volumes:
  es_data:
```

This is missing from your `docker-compose.yml`. Verify against the official repo: https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml